# Is there some module/function in NLTK/SKLearn which will do basic analysis of the text data?

Tags: python, text, nlp, scikit-learn, nltk

I have multiple text files such that each line has exactly one document. I want to do a basic analysis on the text and answer questions like:

- Number of Unigrams
- Average length of doc
- SD of length of doc

etc.

Is there a function in NLTK/SKLEARN to do it? I won't mind additional insights.

Answer (score 1):

1) # of Unigram

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def bigrams(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

with open("data.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.strip().split()
        uni = words
        bi = bigrams(words)
        print uni
        print list(bi)
```

2) Average length of sentence

```
sents = text.split('.')
avg_len = sum(len(x.split()) for x in sents) / len(sents)
```

3) Do it yourself! No API for that.